# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to buid a simple Neural Network and you can find my code below. When I run it I get an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algosofleetNNkuantic2.py", line 41, in <module>
    mlp.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix 
import csv
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


path = "C:\\Users\\YannickLECROART\\Desktop\\modeleimportMD.csv"
file = open(path, newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)
#commandes pour ouvrir et lire un fichier CSV en tant que modele pour le classifieur

header = next(reader) #la 1ere ligne correspond au titre
modele_X = []
modele_Y =  []
#on crée 2 variables que l'on va remplir des données des colonnes du fichier CSV importé pour le modèle
for row in reader: #on va associer les données des colonnes à des variables

    param1  = float(row[0])
    param2 =  float(row[1])
    param3 = float(row[2])
    param4 = float(row[3])
    param5 = float(row[4])
    param6 = float(row[5])
    resultat = str(row[6])
    modele_X.append([param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6]) #on associe ensuite toutes les données collectées à la variable créée plus haut sans tenir compte de la dernière colonne qui correspond au résultat 
    modele_Y.append(resultat) #on associe les données venant de la dernière colonne résultat à la variable créée plus haut et non utilisée pour les prédictions mais utiles pour l'export CSV


le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

enc = LabelEncoder().fit(modele_Y)
Y_encode = enc.transform(modele_Y)
 #print(Y_encode)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(modele_X, Y_encode, test_size = 0.20)

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10, 10), max_iter=1000)  
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)
print(predictions)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))  
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

Comment: .values is generally used to extract the `numpy` array from the `pandas` object. But in your code here, you are not even using `pandas` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error but this worked

```
random_forest.fit(X_train,y_train.ravel())
```

Answer (score 3):

On the line

```
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

`y_train` is of type `numpy.ndarray` and, as staded on the error message

> has no attribute 'values'

If you have properly encoded this array, you should be able to use it simply as

```
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```